# Two dimensional arrays support in terraform

Tags: terraform

Assume the following pseudo code:

```
resource "important_resource" "very_important_name" {
   count = length(var.vip_array)

   very_important_parameter {
     count = length(var.vip_array[count], vips)
     name =  lookup(var.vip_array[count][count], vip.name)
     surname = lookup(var.vip_array[count][count], vip.surname)
   }
}
```

let's say vip_array length is 3 and for each if vip_array element i I have 2 very important people name and surname.

is terraform capable of iterating two dimensional array?

Comment: Definitely in 0.12, but you can check the documentation to verify.

Answer (score 3):

With such a general, contrived initial example it's hard to show a real solution here, but I'll talk about the general patterns involved and hopefully you can adapt them to your real problem.

It looks like your goal is to have one instance of this resource per first-level list element, and then within each instance produce one `very_important_parameter` block per second-level list element. To do this you can use `count` to handle the first level, and a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) for the second:

```
resource "important_resource" "very_important_name" {
   count = length(var.vip_array)

   dynamic "very_important_parameter" {
     for_each = var.vip_array[count.index]
     content {
       name    = very_important_parameter.value.name
       surname = very_important_parameter.value.surname
     }
   }
}
```

Because this uses `count`, it will result in resource instance addresses like `important_resource.very_important_name[0]`, `important_resource.very_important_name[1]`, etc. If you add and remove elements from the middle of your list in `var.vip_array` then it will cause the indices of elements to change and thus may cause more instance updates than you'd like. If instead you can define a logical name for each of your instances, and thus change `var.vip_array` to instead be a map where the keys are those logical names, then you can use resource-level `for_each` instead:

```
resource "important_resource" "very_important_name" {
   for_each = var.vip_map

   dynamic "very_important_parameter" {
     for_each = each.value
     content {
       name    = very_important_parameter.value.name
       surname = very_important_parameter.value.surname
     }
   }
}
```

The advantage of this is that Terraform will then track the individual instances by their map keys. If you have a map key `for_example` then Terraform would create an instance with the address `important_resource.very_important_name["for_example"]`, and then in future if you were to remove that element from the map Terraform will know that it only needs to destroy the one instance associated with that element, and will not disturb any others.

---

Please note that the conventional term for this type kind in Terraform is "list", not "array". While you are free to name the variable whatever you like, it may be best to follow Terraform's conventional naming so that future maintainers of your configuration can more easily refer to the official Terraform documentation to understand what it means.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain and exemplify.